# Proving particular solution in differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Given the second-order ordinary differential equation: 
>   $$
> {y}''+y=f(x)
> $$
>   prove that:
>   $$
> y_p(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(u)\sin(x-u)du
> $$
>   is the particular solution of the equation.

I know this is homework but I've been trying to solve it for the past few days and I can't. I even asked my teacher for help but he doesn't answer.

Thanks.

Comment: try to calculate $y_p''$ using FCT

Comment: How is this a PDE? There's only one independent variable here

Comment: Try to _read_ the differential equation _mentally_: it says "the double derivative of $y$ plus $y$ itself will give us $f(x)$". So, when we need to check if a given $y_P$ is a solution to the deq or not, we need to calculate its double derivative first.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. We assume our $f$ is nice enough to be allowed to use the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule),
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left (\int_{0}^{b(x)}f(x,u)\,du \right) = f\big(x,b(x)\big)\cdot \frac{d}{dx} b(x) + \int_{0}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,u) \,du
$$ giving here
$$
\begin{align}
y'_P(x)&=\frac{d}{dx} \left (\int_{0}^{x}f(u)\sin(x-u)\,du \right) 
\\\\&= 0+ \int_{0}^{x}f(u) \cos(x-u) \,dt
\end{align}
$$ then differentiate once more using the same tool and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Variation of constants tells you to find $y_p$ in the form
$$
y_p(x)=c_1(x)\cos(x)+c_2(x)\sin(x)
$$
where the coefficient functions satisfy the differential equation system
\begin{align}
c_1'(x)\cos x+c_2'(x)\sin x &= 0\\
-c_1'(x)\sin x+c_2'(x)\cos x &= f(x)
\end{align}
which leads to
$$
c_1'(x)=-f(x)\sin x,\ \ c_2'(x)=f(x)\cos(x) 
$$
and thus
$$
y_p(x)=-\int_0^xf(u)\sin u\,du\,\cos x+\int_0^xf(u)\cos u\,du\,\sin x
=\int_0^xf(u)\sin(x-u)\,du.
$$